# In beta site chat rooms, the account suspension message is nearly unreadable

Tags: bug, design, chat, beta-sites, chat-ban

On the Board and Card games chat site, the account suspension message is very difficult to see. In my browser (Chrome on Linux) it looks like this:

[image: image containing low-contrast text that says "your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 18 hours 53 minutes."]

For anyone who has trouble seeing it, that says

> your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 18 hours 53 minutes.

Comment: Not sure if we need to optimize the UX for suspended users ....

Comment: Making messages visible to the people they are addressed to is a pretty low bar. And it's a pain to check, but I bet there are similar problems with other messages about reasons that a user cannot post anything, such as low reputation.

Comment: That looks like a good dupe target, but it's kind of sad to close this as a duplicate of an unaddressed bug that is itself closed as the duplicate of a three-year-old unaddressed bug.